# TikZ: Improving Figure (lines, height, margins, labels)

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix, height

I created code (below) that creates following figure of consecutive processes. I tried my best to write clean and structured code for a good reproduction:

[image: Screenshot]
**Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart, arrows, shadows}

\tikzset{
  bluebox/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle,
  minimum height=4cm,
  fill=blue!25!white,
  align=center,
  inner sep=2ex
  },
  whitebox/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle,
  minimum height=4cm,
  fill=white,
  align=center,
  inner sep=2ex
  },
  item/.style={
  draw,
  inner sep=1ex,
  fill=white 
  },
  matrix/.style={
  draw,
  fill=white,
  text centered,
  minimum height=1em,
  drop shadow
  }
}

\begin{document}

% Stage 1    

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\node[bluebox, label={Header 1}] (Stage1) {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
      inner sep=1ex,fill=white] (Inner) {
      \nodepart{one} A
      \nodepart{two} B
      \nodepart{three} C};
\end{tikzpicture}};

% Stage 2    
\node[bluebox, fill=white, right=of Stage1, label={}] (Stage2) {\rotatebox{90}{Stage 2}};

% Stage 3        
\node[bluebox, right=of Stage2, label={Header 3}] (Stage3) {

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{box}=[matrix, scale=0.75]

    \node[] (row1) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (T1) [box] {$T_w$};
            \node (S1) [box,anchor=north] at (T1.south) {$S_1$};
            \node (S2) [box,anchor=north] at (S1.south) {$S_2$};
            \node (SX) [box,anchor=north] at (S2.south) {$S_m$};
        \end{tikzpicture}};

    \node[right=0pt of row1] (row2) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (T1) [box] {$T_w$};
            \node (S1) [box,anchor=north] at (T1.south) {$S_1$};
            \node (S2) [box,anchor=north] at (S1.south) {$S_2$};
            \node (SX) [box,anchor=north] at (S2.south) {$S_m$};
        \end{tikzpicture}};

    \node[right=0pt of row2] (row3) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (T1) [box] {$T_w$};
            \node (S1) [box,anchor=north] at (T1.south) {$S_1$};
            \node (S2) [box,anchor=north] at (S1.south) {$S_2$};
            \node (SX) [box,anchor=north] at (S2.south) {$S_m$};
        \end{tikzpicture}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[item, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2] (Options) {
        \nodepart{one} Option 1
        \nodepart{two} Option 2};
\end{tikzpicture}};

% Stage 4
\node[whitebox, right=of Stage3, label={}] (Stage4) {\rotatebox{90}{Stage 4}};

% Stage 5
\node[bluebox, right=of Stage4, label={Header 5}] (Stage5) {
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[item,shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, label={Labels}] (Labels) {
          \nodepart{one} "Yes"
          \nodepart{two} "No"};
\end{tikzpicture}};

    \draw[dashed] (Inner.one east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Inner.two east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Inner.three east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Stage2) -- (Stage3);
    \draw[dashed] (Options.one) -- (Stage4);
    \draw[dashed] (Options.two) -- (Stage4);
    \draw[dashed] (Stage4) -- (Stage5);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is an outline of the issues with the figure, though I tried my best to write clean code:

- The matrix in **Stage 3** should be smaller and have less horizontal spacing. Also, all boxes should have the same width
- **Option 1** and **Option 2** should be positioned central and right of the matrix.
- Likewise for *A, B, C*, two dashed lines from **Option 1** and **Option 2** should connect to Stage 4. However, they originate at nodeparts A and C in Stage 1.
- **In Stage 5**, the distance between the item and Labels is too big. I only want to have a small skip
- Last but not least, **all Stage boxes** should have the same height, so that the headers align well.

I hope that you can help to resolve some of the problems? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

It's not convenient to use nested `tikzpictures`, therefore, they have been replaced by `fit` nodes on background layer.

Matrices in stage 3 have been replaced by multipart nodes.

As all `inner` boxes are vertically aligned and it's height is less than `4cm`, all `blueboxes` in background (and labels above them) are also aligned.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart, arrows, shadows, backgrounds, fit}

\tikzset{
  bluebox/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    fill=blue!25!white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  },
  whitebox/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum height=4cm,
    fill=white,
    align=center,
    inner sep=2ex
  },
  item/.style={
    draw,
    inner sep=1ex,
    fill=white 
  },
  matrix/.style={
    draw,
    fill=white,
    text centered,
    minimum height=1em,
    drop shadow
  }
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

% Stage 1     

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=3,
      inner sep=1ex, fill=white] (Inner) {
      \nodepart{one} A
      \nodepart{two} B
      \nodepart{three} C};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[bluebox, fit=(Inner), label=Stage 1] {};
    \end{scope}

% Stage 2    
\node[bluebox, fill=white, right=of Inner, label={}] (Stage2) {\rotatebox{90}{Stage 2}};

% Stage 3        
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,
      inner sep=1ex, fill=white, right=of Stage2] (Inner1) {
      \nodepart{one} $T_w$
      \nodepart{two} $S_1$
      \nodepart{three} $S_2$
      \nodepart{four} $S_m$};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,
      inner sep=1ex, fill=white, right=2mm of Inner1] (Inner2) {
      \nodepart{one} $T_w$
      \nodepart{two} $S_1$
      \nodepart{three} $S_2$
      \nodepart{four} $S_m$};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,
      inner sep=1ex, fill=white, right=2mm of Inner2] (Inner3) {
      \nodepart{one} $T_w$
      \nodepart{two} $S_1$
      \nodepart{three} $S_2$
      \nodepart{four} $S_m$};

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
      inner sep=1ex, fill=white, right=5mm of Inner3] (option) {
      \nodepart{one} Option 1
      \nodepart{two} Option 2};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[bluebox, fit=(Inner1) (option), label=Stage 3] (Stage3) {};
    \end{scope}

% Stage 4
\node[whitebox, right=of option, label={}] (Stage4) {\rotatebox{90}{Stage 4}};

% Stage 5
        \node[draw, shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, fill=white, right=of Stage4, label=Labels] (Labels) {
          \nodepart{one} "Yes"
          \nodepart{two} "No"};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[bluebox, fit=(Labels), label=Stage 5] (Stage5) {};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[dashed] (Inner.one east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Inner.two east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Inner.three east) -- (Stage2);
    \draw[dashed] (Stage2) -- (Stage3);
    \draw[dashed] (option.one east) -- (Stage4);
    \draw[dashed] (option.two east) -- (Stage4);
    \draw[dashed] (Stage4) -- (Stage5);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Only point point: When trying to insert a second % Stage 2 (no matter if bluebox or whitebox), the label does not align with the others :/

Comment: I found: The alignment above the boxes depends upon having for instance a "p" or a "g" in the Label. Any idea?

Comment: @JohnnyJoe insert `\strut` or `\vphantom{g}` inside every label without descendant strokes (I don't know if its the correct term).